# Handling lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a list:

```
  a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

I want to write a program that prints out all the elements of the list that are less than 10.
Actually its pretty simple I got this program but, I need to do it in a single line and I've no idea how to do that. Need some help with this.

Comment: Why do you **need** to do this in a single line?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid did you see in the comments of the answer I asked Pbd the same thing which I have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print [x for x in a if x < 10]
```

Take a further look at [lambda functions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk), I feel this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I got it now it works absolutely fine but, I want to know that can I do this `for x in a && if x<10`.

Comment: You can use python interpreter to test. I did this and it gave me an error saying bool is not iterable, that is probably because `x in a && x < 10` is bool and `for` can't iterate over it

Comment: Ohk I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to print something out of a list that is less than 10 **In the same line**, first you need to create a list:

```
numbers = []
```

loop through every single element of the list

```
for i in a:
```

And then you need a *If statement* to check if the element is less than 10

```
    if i < 10:
```

Append the number to the list

```
        numbers.append(str(i))
```

Join the results together:

```
result = " ".join(numbers)
```

And lastly printing it out

```
print(result)
```

And if you combine everything together, this is what you should get:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
numbers = []
for i in a:
    if i < 10:
        numbers.append(str(i))
result = " ".join(numbers)
print(result)
```

The result should be:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8
```

Comment: @Ashiro I have better solution than this, my problem was that I just want to do it in a single line.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted the result in a single line, If you want the program in one line, you could either use lambda or exec()